# How do you merge a bar plot and a density plot in one with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a simple bar chart using a pandas dataframe and some sample data.  I'd like to create a density plot that shows the distribution frequency pattern in the same plot.  I can't really find a good way of doing that.

Here's what I've got so far...

```
data = [['1-8 miles',14,0.23],['9-16 miles',21,0.35],['17-24 miles',11,0.16],
        ['33-40 miles',4,0.07],['41-46 miles',4,0.07],['Total',60,1.00]]
cols = ['Class Limits','Frequency','Relative Frequency']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = cols)
last_row = len(df)-1
df2 = df[['Class Limits','Relative Frequency']]
df2 = df2.drop(df3.index[last_row])
ax = df2.plot.bar(x='Class Limits', y = 'Relative Frequency')
ax.set_ylabel('Relative Frequency')
```

I don't see a way to automatically merge a distribution plot that shows the distribution frequency on the same plot as the bar chart.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original data and do not mind using another package seaborn:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
sn.distplot(data)
plt.show()
```

The results:

[image]

Comment: Distplot is not for categorical data.

Comment: @jcaliz The data he provided seems binned aggregated data: [1-8], [9-16] ..., If he has the original data, then he can use distplot and specify the bins explicitly. The category of his data is actually consecutive intervals (except for 25~32). It is unusual to draw consecutive intervals as separate categories and at the same time show the density curve. In my understanding, a density curve should have continuous x-axis.